# How to change radio button behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this form:

```
<%= form_for(@submitted_quiz) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :quiz_id, :value => @quiz.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => @quiz.name %>

<%= @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>

<%= f.label question.content %>

<%= question.answers.each do |answer| %>
<%= f.label answer.content %>

<%= f.fields_for (:submitted_answers) do |ff| %>


<%= ff.radio_button :content, value: answer.content %>

<% end #fields_for (:submitted_answers) do %>
<% end #answer.each do  %>
<% end #questions.each do %>


<%= f.submit %>
<% end #form_for  %>
```

But I'm able to check all the radio buttons off, instead of just one radio button per question set (each question has 4 answers and I want to check off only one out of the 5 answers). I know why this is happening, since each `submitted_answers` is unique and I'm constructing a standalone radio button for each of them, but I don't know how to actually fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think `f` is the right solution because `f` is the form holding all questions(so he will only be able to answer one question !!)

Comment: I don't think it should be `ff.radio_button` since I want it to set the `content` value of the submitted answer. If I make it `f.radio_button` it would try and set the `content` value of `submitted_quiz` (which doesn't exist).  

EDIT: what niceman said haha.

Comment: if you inspect the elements with the browser, in what is `ff.radio_button` contained ? `fields_for` shouldn't generate any form tag but what you say suggests that it did

Comment: and may I ask what is the type of `submitted_answers` ? Array ? of what ?

Comment: on second thought, because `fields_for` shouldn't generate form tag, it shouldn't be used here, even if it did work you'll end up with one form for all radio buttons :)

Comment: `submitted_quiz` is a model that `has_many` `submitted_answers`. I'm using nested fields to set the value of the `submitted_answers`, which is done through `fields_for`.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it!

Comment: when you have time, post an answer :)

Comment: I'll post my answer now. Funny thing is, I fixed it but I'm still not 100% sure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting the  `question.answers.each` loop into the `fields_for`. I have a sort-of-maybe idea of how this works but I'm still not 100% sure why this solved it.

```
<%= f.fields_for (:submitted_answers) do |ff| %>

<%= question.answers.each do |answer| %>
<%= ff.label :content, answer.content %>
<%= ff.radio_button :content, answer.content %>

<% end #answer.each do %>
<% end #fields_for (:submitted_answers) do %>
```